# Phonegap: FileTransferError.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap

I'm using the Phonegap file transfer plugin to upload a picture to the server. However I am getting error code: 1 (FileTransferError.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR). I've tested my server code with POSTMAN and I can upload and image successfully. However I get that error with the plugin. This is my code. The file is declared from "camera_image.src" and I can see the image when I append this to the src of an image on the fly. Any contributions? How is this code not perfect?

```
                var fileURL = camera_image.src;     
                alert(fileURL); 
                var win = function (r) {
                    temp.push(r.response);
                    statusDom.innerHTML = "Upload Succesful!";
                }

                var fail = function (error) {
                    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code + " | Source:" + error.source + " | Target:" + error.target );
                    statusDom.innerHTML = "Upload failed!";
                }

                var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                options.fileKey = "properties_photo";
                options.fileName=fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                options.headers = {
                    Connection: "close"
                };

                var params = {};
                params.value1 = "test";
                params.value2 = "param";

                options.params = params;

                var ft = new FileTransfer();

                statusDom = document.querySelector('#status');
                ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
                            if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
                        var perc = Math.floor(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100);
                    statusDom.innerHTML = perc + "% uploaded...";
                            console.log(perc);
                            } else {
                                    if(statusDom.innerHTML == "") {
                                    statusDom.innerHTML = "Loading";
                            } else {
                                    statusDom.innerHTML += ".";
                            }
                        }
                    };
                ft.upload(fileURL, encodeURI("http://cloud10.me/clients/itsonshow/app/image_upload_process.php"), win, fail, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because of spaces in the path or filename of the file to be uploaded.

You need to ensure the plugin isn't being passed a fileURL with %20 in the URL.

Comment: I alerted the URI and it has no spaces at all?